# Visual Studio Code Warning: Also define the standard property 'background-clip' for compatibility

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

[image: VSCode Warning]

I have not tried anything. This is my first time trying to make a website using HTML CSS and Javascript. I am watching a YouTube video and following along entering the code. I have included an image of what code I have so far. It is exactly what is in the video.

Answer (score 0):

This is a warning on the VSCode editor to shows that your CSS might have a bit of issues. In this particular case, it is hinting that the CSS property might have compatibility issue.

Generally, CSS attributes that start with vendor prefixes like `-webkit-` is considered as only available in specific browsers (browser-specific). In this case, referring to the documentation of [`background-clip` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip#browser_compatibility), it seems like newer browsers no longer need this prefix as the implementation and standard is official.

In order to solve this, you can add the unprefixed version of the CSS property in your code like so:

```css
background-clip: text;
```

And the error should disappear.